# How to get all childs of parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want take all things whose contains to meats from one table. In the future whe can create another elements (child ID) to groups (parent ID) e.g now food -> meats -> animal meats -> pig. In the future somebody can create another record with parent id pig sth like this food -> meats -> animal meats -> pig -> bacon and next person can make another record with parent id bacon etc.
How I can make query whose will take all elements whose highest parent is MEATS? so query should return elements pig, cow, bacon.

```
+---------+----------+--------------+
| childId | parentId | name         |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 1       | 0        | FOOD         |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 2       | 1        | FRUITS       |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 3       | 1        | VEGETABLES   |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 4       | 1        | MEATS        |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 5       | 2        | apple        |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 6       | 2        | banana       |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 7       | 3        | carrot       |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 8       | 3        | tomatoes     |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 9       | 4        | FISH MEATS   |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 10      | 4        | ANIMAL MEATS |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 11      | 9        | cod          |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 12      | 9        | salmon       |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 13      | 10       | cow          |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 14      | 10       | pig          |
+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) will do the job:

```
with
x as (
  select childId, parentId, name from t where id = 3
  union all
  select t.childId, t.parentId, t.name
  from x
  join t on t.parentId = x.childId
)
select * from x
```